# Execute action/button when user hits enter

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus

Application uses frameset, where top frame contains banner (form) with searchbox (text field rendered OS style) and button to perform search.

Users want to execute search when they hit enter in that field.

I have already implemented javascript (in Notes client at form level) to catch 13 key and issue button.click(). This was very troublesome (if user keeps application open for long time, Notes client usualy hangs).

I am looking for solution / ideas to make this work - if user hits enter in text field, some action will be invoked (@Formula, LotusScript, JavaScript).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Javascript in the Notes client you can set a timer to poll the search field every, say, half second, and trigger your search function when you see a Newline / CR character in the search field. See this post for more details and actual code sample:
http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/nd6forum.nsf/55c38d716d632d9b8525689b005ba1c0/c7ce0bad6b6ec83385257180007d6761?OpenDocument